# Aligning Query Results in HTML Table

Tags: php, html, mysql, database-design

Saw a similar question w/o answer and I began to wonder how one would go about aligning data from a database.

Let's say I have 3 tables:
States - StateID|StateName
Hurricanes - HurricaneID|HurricaneName
Users - UserID|UserName|StateID|HurricaneID

The goal is to allow users to input their name, and choose a State and a HurricaneName. The combination of the data being stored in the Users table.

Let's say a user can choose a state and a natural event, but once the combination is picked, it can't be picked again. (i.e Tonya -> HurricaneSandy -> NJ, and Tony -> HurricaneSandy -> AL, but no one can choose the combination of state and natural event again).

Desired outcome:

```
+-----------------+----+------+-------+----+
| Hurricane Names | AL | NJ   | MI    | MA |
+-----------------+----+------+-------+----+
| Barry           | -- | Tony | Tonya | -- |
+-----------------+----+------+-------+----+
| Andrew          | -- | --   | Kasey | -- |
+-----------------+----+------+-------+----+
| Sandy           | -- | --   | --    | -- |
+-----------------+----+------+-------+----+
```

I can grab the data for the X and Y axes, but then I can't get the UserName to show up in the table body.

```
The 2 queries used:
$state_query = "SELECT * FROM States ORDER BY StateName ASC";
$state_result = $mysqli->query($state_query);

$table_data_query = "SELECT * FROM Results
RIGHT OUTER JOIN States
USING (StateID)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Hurricanes
USING (HurricaneID)";
$table_data_result = $mysqli->query($table_data_query);




<tbody>

  <?php
     foreach($table_data_result as $t) {
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<th scope="row">' . $t['HurricaneName'] . '</th>';
         foreach($state_result as $i) {
           if($t['StateID'] == $i['StateID'] && $t['StateID'] != NULL) {
              echo '<td>' . $t['UserName'] . '</td>';
            } else 
{ 
echo '<td>--</td>';
}
   }
   echo '</tr>';
}

?>
</tbody>
```

With the code above, you can't get the data to line up. Even then how would the data line up if all Hurricane Names and Table Names have to be displayed, regardless of which UserName is or is not in the database? Am I approaching this incorrectly?

Current (broken) outcome:

```
+-----------------+----+------+-------+----+
| Hurricane Names | AL | NJ   | MI    | MA |
+-----------------+----+------+-------+----+
| Barry           | -- | Tony | --    | -- |
+-----------------+----+------+-------+----+
| Andrew          | -- | Tammy| --    | -- |
+-----------------+----+------+-------+----+
| Andrew          | -- | --   | Kasey | -- |
+-----------------+----+------+-------+----+
```

Results will stack appropriately, but if I have 2 people select the same hurricane, the hurricane name prints twice, instead of the names printing on the same row.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Note that in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate

Comment: (And nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN)

Comment: I have a goal in mind, sure, but I've been failing to fulfill said goal. Even after modifying the query, it has not fixed my HTML output. My first ForEach loop prints out the Hurricane Name, but due to how my query is set up, if 2 people choose a hurricane, the Hurricane Name will be printed out on the table twice.

Comment: Sorry, I can only refer you again to the accepted answer at the link provided.